# Get values from XML with XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I need to extrapolate a series of values ​​through XPath queries from XML files that I report here.
In particular i want read tag

```
&lt;IDdocumento&gt;0406304e92814307b6f4aedbece1670a&lt;/IDdocumento&gt;
```

extracting the value **0406304e92814307b6f4aedbece1670a&lt**

and the following tags like

Anno fiscale extracting **2019**

Codice fiscale intestatario fattura extracting **00532730371**

Ragione sociale o cognome e nome extracting **OBER SPA**

I tried whit a query like for example

```
//attribute[@code="ANNOFISC"/@name="Anno fiscale"]/@value
```

but to no avail

Could you kindly give me suggestions?
Many thanks in advance who can help

Goodbye

```
&lt;attribute code="ANNOFISC" name ="Anno fiscale"  value="2019"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCALE" name ="Codice fiscale intestatario fattura"  value="00532730371"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCAZI" name ="Codice fiscale azienda"  value="00543720981"/&gt;

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sincro:IdC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sincro="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/ http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/IdC.xsd" sincro:url="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" sincro:version="1.0"><sincro:SelfDescription><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">1a769149a67d41fca5f6316a70e19cfb</sincro:ID><sincro:CreatingApplication><sincro:Name>Conservazione digitale Zucchetti</sincro:Name><sincro:Version>2.3</sincro:Version><sincro:Producer>Zucchetti SPA</sincro:Producer></sincro:CreatingApplication></sincro:SelfDescription><sincro:VdC><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">0ac79c41a62d4ddaa565c0bb9f4a8e1d</sincro:ID><sincro:VdCGroup><sincro:Label>Documenti contabili e fiscali</sincro:Label><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">4a739b70450b473ab0a7bee071b1276c</sincro:ID><sincro:Description sincro:language="it">Documenti contabili e fiscali</sincro:Description></sincro:VdCGroup></sincro:VdC><sincro:FileGroup><sincro:Label>Documenti contabili e fiscali</sincro:Label><sincro:File sincro:encoding="binary" sincro:extension="xml" sincro:format="application/xml"><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">0406304e92814307b6f4aedbece1670a</sincro:ID><sincro:Path>IT00532730371_003MZ.xml</sincro:Path><sincro:Hash sincro:canonicalXML="true" sincro:function="SHA-256">771A44BB6507BE077C8D5D7D81EEF3657DE588E43C913E118223E2FB0BFE710C</sincro:Hash><sincro:MoreInfo sincro:XMLScheme="file:///var/www/webapps/infinitycodi/WEB-INF/XMLSchema/sincro_file.xsd"><sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
    &lt;document ownercode="" extcode="" description="IT00532730371_003MZ.xml"&gt;
    &lt;datachiusura&gt;24/11/2019 13:35:27&lt;/datachiusura&gt;
    &lt;oggettodocumento&gt;Fatture Passive&lt;/oggettodocumento&gt;
    &lt;soggettoproduttore&gt;
    &lt;ragionesociale&gt;FORNITURE TECNICHE INDUSTRIALI ABC&lt;/ragionesociale&gt;
    &lt;codicefiscale&gt;00704580166&lt;/codicefiscale&gt;
    &lt;partitaiva&gt;00543720981&lt;/partitaiva&gt;
    &lt;/soggettoproduttore&gt;
    &lt;destinatario&gt;
    &lt;ragionesociale&gt;Sistema di Conservazione&lt;/ragionesociale&gt;
    &lt;/destinatario&gt;
    &lt;IDdocumento&gt;0406304e92814307b6f4aedbece1670a&lt;/IDdocumento&gt;
    &lt;attributes class="FATTURAPASSIVA" name = "Fatture Passive                                   "&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="ANNOFISC" name ="Anno fiscale"  value="2019"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCALE" name ="Codice fiscale intestatario fattura"  value="00532730371"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCAZI" name ="Codice fiscale azienda"  value="00543720981"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODSOG" name ="Codice azienda"  value="000000000000245"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="DATADOC" name ="Data documento"  value="20191030"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="DATRIC" name ="Data ricezione del documento"  value="20191031"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="IDDOCUMEN" name ="Identificativo univoco del documento"  value="naejcixpihykbmdi"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="NUMERODOC" name ="Numero documento"  value="V1  002052"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="PARTITAIVA" name ="Partita IVA"  value="00513531202"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="RAGSOC" name ="Ragione sociale o cognome e nome"  value="OBER SPA"/&gt;
    &lt;/attributes&gt;
    &lt;/document&gt;</sincro:EmbeddedMetadata></sincro:MoreInfo></sincro:File><sincro:File sincro:encoding="binary" sincro:extension="xml" sincro:format="application/xml"><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">b7962a12d44441f9a59cc1cb4824960a</sincro:ID><sincro:Path>IT02355260981_3zAcj.xml.p7m</sincro:Path><sincro:Hash sincro:canonicalXML="true" sincro:function="SHA-256">148237FBCFF5B310DB4B0B3B48F13C3BB886CA124B86E20C1F5F46202AF762C6</sincro:Hash><sincro:MoreInfo sincro:XMLScheme="file:///var/www/webapps/infinitycodi/WEB-INF/XMLSchema/sincro_file.xsd"><sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
    &lt;document ownercode="" extcode="" description="IT02355260981_3zAcj.xml.p7m"&gt;
    &lt;datachiusura&gt;31/10/2019 - 14:56:46&lt;/datachiusura&gt;
    &lt;oggettodocumento&gt;Fatture Passive&lt;/oggettodocumento&gt;
    &lt;soggettoproduttore&gt;
    &lt;ragionesociale&gt;FORNITURE TECNICHE INDUSTRIALI ABC&lt;/ragionesociale&gt;
    &lt;codicefiscale&gt;00704580166&lt;/codicefiscale&gt;
    &lt;partitaiva&gt;00543720981&lt;/partitaiva&gt;
    &lt;/soggettoproduttore&gt;
    &lt;destinatario&gt;
    &lt;ragionesociale&gt;Sistema di Conservazione&lt;/ragionesociale&gt;
    &lt;/destinatario&gt;
    &lt;IDdocumento&gt;b7962a12d44441f9a59cc1cb4824960a&lt;/IDdocumento&gt;
    &lt;attributes class="FATTURAPASSIVA" name = "Fatture Passive                                   "&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="ANNOFISC" name ="Anno fiscale"  value="2019"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCALE" name ="Codice fiscale intestatario fattura"  value="05891470154"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODFISCAZI" name ="Codice fiscale azienda"  value="00543720981"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="CODSOG" name ="Codice azienda"  value="000000000000245"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="DATADOC" name ="Data documento"  value="20191031"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="DATRIC" name ="Data ricezione del documento"  value="20191031"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="IDDOCUMEN" name ="Identificativo univoco del documento"  value="bpogsznntdynvxgt"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="NUMERODOC" name ="Numero documento"  value="E00797"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="PARTITAIVA" name ="Partita IVA"  value="05891470154"/&gt;
    &lt;attribute code="RAGSOC" name ="Ragione sociale o cognome e nome"  value="TUNGSTEN CARBIDE TOOLS S.R.L."/&gt;
    &lt;/attributes&gt;
    &lt;/document&gt;</sincro:EmbeddedMetadata></sincro:MoreInfo></sincro:File><sincro:File sincro:encoding="binary" sincro:extension="xml" sincro:format="application/xml"><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">2ea9e60ef1764f6b9b8e14ac4916b5e3</sincro:ID><sincro:Path>704a5022a86644c3b280daf818d7142f.xml.p7m</sincro:Path><sincro:Hash sincro:canonicalXML="true" sincro:function="SHA-256">E53FCB957DD40B653C49C1A634DFD37823CCC50213D9FF140BA7F9AD2060FF13</sincro:Hash></sincro:File><sincro:File sincro:encoding="binary" sincro:extension="tsr" sincro:format="application/timestamp-reply"><sincro:ID sincro:scheme="local">f42db62908674debb650bd4dd2afcb11</sincro:ID><sincro:Path>704a5022a86644c3b280daf818d7142f.tsr</sincro:Path><sincro:Hash sincro:canonicalXML="true" sincro:function="SHA-256">E6EB052B6B998692DBD92029B82DE87AB4646788A2DAD7E53C160C2F756E42FB</sincro:Hash></sincro:File></sincro:FileGroup><sincro:Process><sincro:Agent sincro:type="person" sincro:role="PreservationManager"><sincro:AgentName><sincro:NameAndSurname><sincro:FirstName>ITALO</sincro:FirstName><sincro:LastName>BERTOLI</sincro:LastName></sincro:NameAndSurname></sincro:AgentName><sincro:Agent_ID sincro:scheme="TaxCode">IT:BRTTLI43M24L087K</sincro:Agent_ID><sincro:MoreInfo sincro:XMLScheme="file:///var/www/webapps/infinitycodi/WEB-INF/XMLSchema/sincro_agent.xsd"><sincro:EmbeddedMetadata>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;Roles&gt;&lt;Role Name= "Responsabile del servizio di conservazione"&gt;&lt;RoleType Name= "Responsabile"&gt;&lt;Companyname&gt;ZUCCHETTI SPA&lt;/Companyname&gt;&lt;NameSurname&gt;&lt;Name&gt;&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Surname&gt;&lt;/Surname&gt;&lt;/NameSurname&gt;&lt;AddressRole&gt;&lt;Address&gt;VIA SOLFERINO&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;CivicNumber&gt;1&lt;/CivicNumber&gt;&lt;City&gt;LODI&lt;/City&gt;&lt;Province&gt;LO&lt;/Province&gt;&lt;/AddressRole&gt;&lt;TaxCode&gt;05006900962&lt;/TaxCode&gt;&lt;FiscalCode&gt;05006900962&lt;/FiscalCode&gt;&lt;DateStartAssignment&gt;01/09/2015&lt;/DateStartAssignment&gt;&lt;/RoleType&gt;&lt;RoleType Name= "Delegato"&gt;&lt;Companyname&gt;CAMIA PAOLO&lt;/Companyname&gt;&lt;NameSurname&gt;&lt;Name&gt;PAOLO&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Surname&gt;CAMIA&lt;/Surname&gt;&lt;/NameSurname&gt;&lt;AddressRole&gt;&lt;Address&gt;VIA SOLFERINO&lt;/Address&gt;&lt;CivicNumber&gt;1&lt;/CivicNumber&gt;&lt;City&gt;LODI&lt;/City&gt;&lt;Province&gt;LO&lt;/Province&gt;&lt;/AddressRole&gt;&lt;TaxCode&gt;&lt;/TaxCode&gt;&lt;FiscalCode&gt;CMAPLA64H04B910C&lt;/FiscalCode&gt;&lt;DateStartAssignment&gt;23/06/2017&lt;/DateStartAssignment&gt;&lt;/RoleType&gt;&lt;/Role &gt;&lt;/Roles&gt;</sincro:EmbeddedMetadata></sincro:MoreInfo></sincro:Agent><sincro:TimeReference><sincro:DetachedTimeStamp sincro:normal="2021-11-08T11:25:44.102Z" sincro:encoding="binary" sincro:format="                              ">1a769149a67d41fca5f6316a70e19cfb.tsr</sincro:DetachedTimeStamp></sincro:TimeReference><sincro:LawAndRegulations sincro:language="it">- Codice Civile [Libro Quinto Del lavoro, Titolo II Del lavoro nell'impresa, Capo III Delle imprese commerciali e delle altre imprese soggette a registrazione, Sezione III Disposizioni particolari per le imprese commerciali, Paragrafo 2 Delle scritture contabili], articolo 2215 bis - Documentazione informatica;
    - Legge 7 agosto 1990, n. 241 e s.m.i. – Nuove norme in materia di procedimento amministrativo e di diritto di accesso ai documenti amministrativi;
    - Decreto del Presidente della Repubblica 28 dicembre 2000, n. 445 e s.m.i. – Testo Unico delle disposizioni legislative e regolamentari in materia di documentazione amministrativa;
    - Regolamento (UE) 2016/679 del Parlamento europeo e del Consiglio, del 27 aprile 2016, relativo alla protezione delle persone fisiche con riguardo al trattamento dei dati
    personali, nonché alla libera circolazione di tali dati e che abroga la direttiva 95/46/CE (regolamento generale sulla protezione dei dati), applicabile in tutti gli Stati membri a partire dal 25 maggio 2018;
    - Decreto Legislativo 22 gennaio 2004, n. 42 e s.m.i. – Codice dei Beni Culturali e del Paesaggio;
    - Decreto Legislativo 7 marzo 2005 n. 82 e s.m.i. – Codice dell'amministrazione digitale (CAD);
    - Decreto del Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri 22 febbraio 2013 – Regole tecniche in materia di generazione, apposizione e verifica delle firme elettroniche avanzate, qualificate e digitali ai sensi degli articoli 20, comma 3, 24, comma 4, 28, comma 3, 32, comma3, lettera b), 35, comma 2, 36, comma 2, e 71;
    - Decreto del Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri 3 dicembre 2013 - Regole tecniche in materia di sistema di conservazione ai sensi degli articoli 20, commi 3 e 5-bis, 23-ter, comma 4, 43, commi 1 e 3, 44 , 44-bis e 71, comma 1, del Codice dell'amministrazione digitale di cui al decreto legislativo n. 82 del 2005;
    - Decreto del Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri 3 dicembre 2013 - Regole tecniche per il protocollo informatico ai sensi degli articoli 40-bis ,41,47,57-bis e 71, comma 1, del Codice dell'amministrazione digitale di cui al decreto legislativo n. 82 del 2005;
    - Decreto del Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri 13 novembre 2014, Regole tecniche in materia di formazione, trasmissione, copia, duplicazione, riproduzione e validazione temporale dei documenti informatici nonché di formazione e conservazione dei documenti informatici delle pubbliche amministrazioni ai sensi degli articoli 20, 22, 23-bis, 23-ter, 40, comma 1, 41, e 71, comma 1, del Codice dell'amministrazione digitale di cui al decreto legislativo n. 82 del 2005.
    - Decreto MEF del 17 giugno 2014 - Modalità di assolvimento degli obblighi fiscali relativi ai documenti informatici ed alla loro riproduzione su diversi tipi di supporto – articolo 21, comma 5, del decreto legislativo n. 82/2005. (Ministero dell'economia e delle finanze);
    - Decreto del Presidente del Consiglio dei Ministri 13 novembre 2014 - Regole tecniche in materia di formazione, trasmissione, copia, duplicazione, riproduzione e validazione temporale dei documenti informatici nonché di formazione e conservazione dei documenti informatici delle pubbliche amministrazioni ai sensi degli articoli 20, 22, 23-bis, 23-ter, 40, comma 1, 41, e 71, comma 1, del Codice dell'amministrazione digitale di cui al decreto legislativo n. 82 del 2005;
    - Circolare AgID 10 aprile 2014, n. 65 - Modalità per l'accreditamento e la vigilanza sui soggetti pubblici e privati che svolgono attività di conservazione dei documenti informatici di cui all'articolo 44-bis, comma 1, del decreto legislativo 7 marzo 2005, n. 82;
    - Il Regolamento (UE) n. 910/2014 eIDAS (electronic IDentification Authentication and Signature), costituisce una base normativa comune per i Paesi membri dell'U.E. per quanto riguarda i servizi fiduciari, i mezzi di identificazione elettronica e le modalità di interazioni elettroniche sicure fra cittadini, imprese e pubbliche amministrazioni.</sincro:LawAndRegulations></sincro:Process></sincro:IdC>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your question to add some formatting: hopefully I've captured your intent.

What you seem to have here is an XML document containing an element `syncro:EmbeddedMetaData` whose content is a text node containing an escaped lexical XML document. That's a pretty weird design. To access the content of that inner document you need to go through two phases of XML parsing. This can be done in XPath 3.1 or XQuery 3.1 using the `parse-xml()` function, for example

```
parse-xml(//syncro:EmbeddedMetaData)
   //attribute[@code="ANNOFISC"]/@value
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Kay for help
unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in my case The problem is that this query must be set in an application that extracts the values, applying the suggested statement 
the software prompts an error message that says: "the namespace prefix 'syncro' is not defined '
I can read the entire content of the XML by applying the "command"   /   , but they are not manageable as the values are all grouped together
I am grateful for any further suggestions
Bye

enter image description here

Comment: If you use a namespace prefix in an XPath expression then of course you must declare it. If you use XQuery then the declaration can appear in a "declare namespace" clause in the query prolog; if you use XPath then the way you do it depends on the API of your XPath processor. (I see I used the prefix `syncro` whereas the source document uses `sincro` - that difference wasn't intended, but it doesn't actually matter, so long as you bind it to the namespace `http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/`).

Comment: Hello  I tried to change the expression by typing     parse-xml(//sincro:EmbeddedMetaData//attribute[@code="ANNOFISC"]/@value
And also by entering the prefix of thenames as suggested Unfortunately my software tells me "Function not recognized" I think  the expression that is not recognized is:   parse-xml      My application works according to practically the same rules as this online tester    https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-tester-online.php even here an unrecognized expression is reported if i write parse-xml Do you think there are others options? thank you very much

Comment: As I mentioned, `parse-xml()` requires XPath 3.1 or XQuery 3.1. Doing this with XPath 1.0 will be much more difficult; you'll need to extract the inner XML with one path expression, parse it in the calling application, and then use a second path expression to look inside it.